# How can I serve requests to a client without refreshing the user's session?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security

I have an app which we would like to implement some "real-time" polling in by hitting an endpoint with a certain frequency. However this update needs to not refresh the session, so that the session can be timed out at the last action that wasn't this poll.

Is there a way to exclude some routes from updating the user's session expiry, but still requiring a user's session for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If the "reflreshing" request bears the `jsessionid` token, the session will be automatically refreshed. So you must do only unauthenticated (ie. no `jsessionid`) requests to the endpoint.

So, how do you relate this request to an existing user without its session id ? 
You could add headers to the request, containing enough informations to identify the user on the server side (for example, a JWT token). A `HttpFilter` could protect the endpoint and perform the authentification based on this token.

Now, there is another problem.
To determine if there are new data available for this particular user, I assume the endpoint will have to query the user's state. If that state is entirely store into the user's `HttpSession`, you're screwed - it cannot be accessed programmatically, only via a `jsessionid`, which refreshes the timeout.

The solution here would be to externalize the user's data (or at least, those relevant to the real-time stuff) into another storage system (an in-memory Map, a Redis cache, an Oracle or MongoDB database...).

This requires quite some work indeed...